How different is the quality of steel from World War I that use with mark I tank, compared to today's high-grade steel?
I mean in our modern era, high grade steel exist like "super steel" technology,
how strong of WW1 tank grade steel compare modern high-end quality of steel?
https://scitechdaily.com/major-breakthrough-in-super-steel-project-high-strength-steel-at-unprecedented-levels-of-fracture-resistance/
https://www.hku.hk/press/news_detail_16681.html

https://youtu.be/hFn5Mi3JlMM?si=u3uUZgD3b4yC8pMi

Strength of steel or any materials are available - why don't you check the numbers?

Part of the problem with these comparisons of old armor vs modern armor is that most old armors were mild steel where modern armors are hardened.

Find the material designation of ww1 tank steel.  Compare the properties of that with whatever modern steel material you wish.

WWI metallurgy was far less advanced. An instructive example are the hull plates from which the Titanic was built two years earlier. Samples retrieved from the wreck show sulfur content so high as to move the ductile-to-brittle transition temperature to above the ocean temperature at the time the ship sank. When presented with a shock load, the plates then shattered instead of yielded.
This theoretically could present a problem for a tank exposed to subzero temperatures on a winter battlefield, but I do not know if this was encountered in practice.
